# Find a word in array string and add bold to it Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a page that shows each time a different quote from an array with a function that iterates through them. So what I want to also add is that for each string that is being displayed to find a specific word and make it bolder. In this case "Text" I want to make it bolder.

JS:

```
var facts = [
    "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet. - by Test",
    "Lorem Ipsum amet dolor sit. - by Test",
    "Lorem amet Ipsum. - by Test",
    "Lorem Nopsum sit amet. - by Test",
];

!function newFact() {
    var randomFact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
    document.getElementById('factDisplay').innerHTML = facts[randomFact]
}();
```

HTML

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="quote" id="factDisplay"></div>
    </section>
<body>
</html>
```

It can be either Vanilla JS or jQuery.

I also have tried this but is not working as I'm getting an error: "facts.replace is not a function"

```
facts.replace('Test', '<b>Test</b>')
```

I have also tried But not working:

```
var wordsToBold = ["test"];
function makeBold(input, wordsToBold) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(' + wordsToBold.join('|') + ')(\\b)', 'ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
document.getElementById("factDisplay").innerHTML = makeBold(facts, wordsToBold);
```

Comment: Use the replace on `facts[randomfact]` which is a string. `replace()` is not an array method

Comment: `facts` is an array not a `string`. You can only use `replace` on `strings`.

Comment: @SAM do you know any other method?

Comment: @charlietfl can you make a working snippet or share the code here?

Comment: onvert to title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the `fact` from the `facts` array and make it bold using `replace`.

```js
var facts = [
  "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet. - by Test",
  "Lorem Ipsum amet dolor sit. - by Test",
  "Lorem amet Ipsum. - by Test",
  "Lorem Nopsum sit amet. - by Test",
];

!(function newFact() {
  var randomFact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
  document.getElementById("factDisplay").innerHTML = facts[randomFact].replace(
    "Test",
    "<b>Test</b>"
  );
})();
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="quote" id="factDisplay"></div>
</section>
```

**BOLD MULTIPLE WORDS: REMEMBER, it will only bold the words that you specify in an array and that is present in the `str` that you pass to function `makeBoldWordsFromString`**

```js
var facts = [
  "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet. - by Test",
  "Lorem Ipsum amet dolor sit. - by Test",
  "Lorem amet Ipsum. - by Test",
  "Lorem Nopsum sit amet. - by Test",
];

function makeBoldWordsFromString(str, wordArray) {
  wordArray.forEach((word) => {
    str = str.replace(word, `<b>${word}</b>`);
  });
  return str;
}

!(function newFact() {
  var randomFact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
  const str = facts[randomFact];
  document.getElementById(
    "factDisplay"
  ).innerHTML = makeBoldWordsFromString(str, ["Test", "dolor", "Lorem"]);
})();
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="quote" id="factDisplay"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes is working, I will accept an as good answer, but before that, I have a question, how to bold multiple words?

Comment: make a function and then pass the word that you want to bold and on which string. Easy

Comment: can you help me with that, with another edit?

Comment: Edited but remember it will only bold the words that you specify in an array and that is present in the `str`